# Perpetual motion machines and supersonic flight

Tags: science-based, flight, perpetual-motion

Related to [Perpetual motion machines and rocketry](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/203192/perpetual-motion-machines-and-rocketry).
In my current worldbuilding project, people commonly employ enigmatic Clarkean machines called "spinners". They are two adjoined cubes, counter-rotating and effectively unstoppable. No amount of counter-torque can slow their rate of rotation. In addition, the speed at which the cubes rotate against each other can be "programmed" through a dizzying and convoluted series of mathematical instructions--a two-way mathematical dialogue via EM communication, where difficulty steps up in tandem with faster rotation. Some people have spent their entire lives unraveling and refining the rules that coax spinners up to greater and greater speeds.
Spinners are used in everything from portable heaters and electricity to vehicles and aircraft. Simple, dumb control circuitry can encourage lesser speeds from spinners, while the greatest speeds require computers of vast capability.
(In addition to speed, **size** may also be ordered in this way. Each cube is by default 20 cm to a side--about the span of 2 credit cards. They can be ordered to twice that in width and height and six times that in "length" parallel to the rotation axis. From two 20x20x20 cm cubes to two 40x40x120 cm rectangular "rods", and anywhere in between. It's also important to note that spinners have tensile & compressive strengths greater than any manmade material, they don't experience creep or stress deformation, and they start vaporizing at 8000 K.)

My civilization is entering an age of high-altitude and orbital flight, and I would expect the application of these magical spinners may reach far into that domain. A fully extended spinner, two rectangular bars each twice as wide/high as a hand and over a meter long, may deliver an enormous amount of torque.

Aviation is outside my familiar research. Originally, I imagined a fan-powered supersonic aircraft, but as I started to look into it I saw a lot of doubt about whether a fan motor could do any useful work with a supersonic intake. Some comments I've seen say it is impossible. Supersonic shocks on the fan blades would cut the flight short and ensure a rough landing, no known material could withstand the stresses.
My previous question asked about rocket flight and how spinners would be involved in producing thrust with fuel and out of an atmosphere. This question is somewhat the opposite: how spinners may be used in producing thrust without fuel and in an atmosphere--supersonically.
Is my spinner-powered, supersonic fan motor impossible, or is that an unqualified conjecture? Is there a better hypothetical way to use spinners to achieve supersonic flight?

Comment: You probably try to get the cubes to rotate as **slow** as possible. Whatever you do with the cubes, the part where the not indestructible material is attached to the cubes shouldn't shear or be pulverised. With infinite power it doesn't matter how fast it goes. Just that it goes. With going slower you have a better chance of balancing the system to the max, so the connection points won't shatter.

Comment: @Trioxidane doesn't the counter-torque translate "down" the gear train as well, though? Wouldn't it be better to attach a super-fast spinner directly to the fan blade? Have it act as the stator and rotor?

Comment: It depends a bit. I expect these things to be relatively rare, so you would want to squeeze out as much power from them as possible. In the end there is only so much material can handle. Dynamos, gears or anything else will eventually hit a limit. In a way the speed doesn't matter. There is simply a maximum of energy that leaks into the components, making heat or stress that will break the whole thing. But if you only want to turn a fan to move an airplane, a faster one is more efficient.

Comment: Easy way to prove that the spinners can power the engines of a supersonic aircraft: you can always convert mechanical power into electric power with little loss, and then electric power into heat, again with little loss. So you have an inexhaustible source of heat, which can serve to power a reaction engine.

Comment: @AlexP whether the energy for supersonic travel is available wasn't a concern, it's more like whether our manmade materials can use that energy to that end without disintegrating.

Comment: @Trioxidane spinners aren't rare enough to justify using only one as a powerplant for a supersonic aircraft. They're a fairly common commodity, each family typically has one powering/heating their home. They're about as common as an automobile to the typical American family.

Comment: If these spinners are unstoppable why worry about making them faster? Just add gears at a suitable ratio.

Comment: @DrMcCleod counter-torque would eventually warp and destroy the gears. With our manmade materials, there's a limit to how much torque (force x area) that can be applied. By gearboxes alone, I've found that this severely limits the power you can draw from one.

Comment: The limit of energy creation by one cube would be the material strength. If I fit the cube in gear of X meters in diameter, I can simply add more and more gears going off that single one to transer all the power I want... up to the point that the place where the cube fits into the gear deforms with all the stress forces. Speed would only be a factor in miniaturizing the gear that you build around the cube, for a space shuttle with little space to spare you probably want a small gear. This means that the size of the cube and it's turning area are far more important.

Comment: @Demigan there's a maximum amount of energy you can siphon from a cube, which is dependent on its surface area. Adjusting speed helps to miniaturize the gear train, but that energy withdrawal limit stays the same. That's not the only factor speed plays. The cubes are inordinarily durable. High speeds let you garner more energy in exotic ways. Turning one at ridiculous rpm and smacking air molecules for example.

Comment: It seems a number of answers to your rocket question already includes supersonic atmospheric flight capabilities as part of their answers.

Comment: An important limitation for the fast/slow spin discussion would be how to engage the drive of the system. If the cube rotation rates are set and fixed until a grounded system changes them, practically controlling the throttle of an aircraft with a high spin cube would be difficult. How would I safely engage a drive system to something already spinning that fast?

Comment: @Zer0ah Spinners have to be coaxed to maintain speed via an EM "dialogue", otherwise they're stationary. For small rates of rotation <1 Hz they can be driven by simple, dumb control circuits. As you go higher, the dialogue changes. You need more advanced circuitry to process the return signals and output the correct signals for it to maintain speed. Higher and higher, you require more advanced computers for data process and return. To start a prop-like aircraft, a moderately sophisticated computer would smoothly execute the commands to bring the spinners up to speed.

Comment: They are intentionally designed this way to not be super overpowered (as they would become in the hands of humans). The "dialogue" is mathematically convoluted. Ranges of rotation speeds are broken into discrete steps governed by different annoyingly complex "rules", no one brilliant mathematician is going to crack a code to unlock all potential speeds overnight.

Comment: @BMF That makes sense, I was under the impression that the spin and size settings were states maintained until an overwriting command signal was provided, but I see now that they need to receive a sustained signal (or alternatively, no signal is the overwriting command signal). This implies some interesting interactions for spinners changing state: an engineer in your setting might be interested in study how quickly these change speed and size, you might actually get some interesting capabilities from rapidly deforming the spinner head if it is fast enough, or a hydraulic press otherwise

Comment: @Zer0ah Oh, that's a good point, using one as a press. I hadn't really thought about the applications of the shape-shifting. I wonder if rapid deformation could be as useful for energy production as the rotation. (Although, I think *really rapid* deformation would be kinda ridiculous lol. The rate at which it deforms could be inversely proportional to its current volume (and maybe raised to some power, for reasonableness). At default size, the cubes could "vibrate", growing & shrinking slightly yet rapidly. At large sizes, the cubes could take minutes to inflate/deflate.)

Comment: I had thought about its use as a weapon. If you could "talk louder" than the control circuitry attached to a spinner-motor and coax it to increase/decrease size, you could permanently damage the machinery. Could be a weapon to use against cities and enemy aircraft, etc. Of course, military applications would be well-shielded against.

Comment: @BMF when turning in liquids or gasses it is the total resistance that it would normally offer that generates (movement) energy. So having a larger surface area and heavier liquids would be key. To improve on that you would need to add fans and increase the surface area. But why waste energy on moving the liquid if you can extract it directly from the fans itself? Using the strongest material on the surface area is the way to go as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Electric planes and carriers**

Electric planes have been a popular concept for a long time, held back by one key factor. Gasoline and other oils are much more power dense than batteries. Electric planes have a shorter range.

Your perpetual motion machines change that. Put a generator on the plane and they can have an immensely powerful engine.

The early applications, before they finished engines, would probably be transport.

Quoting the wiki page.

> While the batteries weigh more than the equivalent in fuel, electric motors weigh less than their piston-engine counterparts and in smaller aircraft used for shorter flights, can improve the disparity between electric and gasoline energy densities.

You could have extremely powerful fan motors which could transport huge amounts of goods. Massive amounts of bombs, thick shielding, or huge amounts of supplies. This would be a good route towards making a flying fortress like the helicarrier from avengers. If power is no object, you can carry a huge amount of weaponry.

Supplies and resources are the backbone of war. Your spinners let whichever side has better spinners transport massive amounts of supplies, including fuel ran jet engines, anywhere.

If electricity was a viable contender for jet engines this [electrical jet engine](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/full/10.1063/5.0005814) would likely have been invented a lot earlier. You would probably start with hybrid engines, which would use the massive power reserves of electricity to empower jets, and work towards purely electrical planes.